# How to extract model from backbone collection on the basis of a field which is array of JSON

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a collection of models in which model contains a field say data, which is array of JSON.

```
data [{x : 3, y:4}]
```

Now I want to use **where** function of backbone collection as :

```
var model= coll.where ({
data : data
})
```

it gives no output. 
I am not sure whether i am doing right or something missing. Please guide me for this soluiotn

Comment: is data inside each or your models wrapped inside `data`?

Comment: so add this line wherever you are adding values to your model `model.set(model.toJSON().data)` so that your model will directly contain properties and you can follow the examples from backbonejs.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at how [`where`](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/1.0.0/backbone.js#L796) works:

```
where: function(attrs, first) {
  if (_.isEmpty(attrs)) return first ? void 0 : [];
  return this[first ? 'find' : 'filter'](function(model) {
    for (var key in attrs) {
      if (attrs[key] !== model.get(key)) return false;
    }
    return true;
  });
}
```

you'll see that it just scanning the models and comparing attributes using `!==`. When you using `!==` or `===` (or `!=` or `==` for that matter) to compare arrays, the references are compared, not the content; for example, this is false:

```
[1] === [1]
```

The result is that searching for an array using [`where`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-where) doesn't work that well, `where` is meant to be a shortcut for searching for simple scalar values.

If you need to search for an array, then you can use [`filter`](http://underscorejs.org/#filter) directly and you can use [`_.isEqual`](http://underscorejs.org/#isEqual) to help you compare things:

```
var models = coll.filter(function(m) {
    return _.isEqual(m.get('a'), data);
});
```

If you want one match, use [`find`](http://underscorejs.org/#find) instead of `filter`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/PZZv4/1/

Comment: But i have both scaler and array values in one model. in that case what willl be good approach ?

Comment: Yes, `filter`/`find` with `_.isEqual` would work for scalars and arrays.